# Slice integer parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a class that gets an integer parameter pack `[a,b,...,y,z]`. I need to expand it into two packs `[a,...,y]` and `[b,...,z]` - that is remove once the first and once the last. The end product is supposed to be a bunch of 2-d arrays sized `[a,b]`,`[b,c]`, etc. until `[x,y]`,`[y,z]`. I am trying to use something like this:

```
std::tuple< std::array< std::array< int, /*RemoveFirst*/Ints>, /*RemoveLast*/Ints>...>
```

I am open to other solutions, too.

**Example:**

```
template <int... Ints>
struct S {
  std::tuple< std::array< std::array< int, /*RemoveFirst*/Ints>, /*RemoveLast*/Ints>...> t;
};
int main() {
  S<2,3,4> a;
  std::get<0>(a.t)[0][0] = 42;
  // explenation:
  // a.t               is tuple<array<array<int,3>,2>,array<array<int,4>,3>>
  // get<0>(a.t)       is array<array<int,3>,2>
  // get<0>(a.t)[0]    is array<int,3>
  // get<0>(a.t)[0][0] is int
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the following code

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
auto constexpr bar (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return
      std::tuple<
         std::array<
            std::array<int,
                       std::tuple_element_t<Is+1u, T>::value>,
            std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>::value>...
      >{}; }

template <std::size_t ... Is>
auto constexpr foo ()
 { return bar<std::tuple<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>>
             (std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1u>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto f = foo<2u, 3u, 5u, 7u, 11u>();

   using typeTuple = std::tuple<
      std::array<std::array<int, 3u>, 2u>,
      std::array<std::array<int, 5u>, 3u>,
      std::array<std::array<int, 7u>, 5u>,
      std::array<std::array<int, 11u>, 7u>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<typeTuple const, decltype(f)>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: I am not looking for an array of pairs. I am looking for a collection of 2-d arrays, which I think is quite different.

Comment: @Baruch - sorry but I don't understand what do you exactly want; please, could you add an example?

Comment: I added an example. I hope it clarifies

Comment: @Baruch - OK. If I understand correctly what you want, the modified answer should works.

Comment: @Baruch - Answer simplified a little (no more `getVal()`; tuple passed as type, not as value anymore).

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, too. I also added `template<std::size_t... I> using MyType = decltype(foo<I...>)` so I can use it as a type in declerations